# How do I remove a group from an xcode project using AppleScript

Tags: applescript

I've successfully managed to add files to a group with AppleScript, but I also need to be able to remove a child group.
I thought something like

```
tell currentGroup
    --remove any groups already present
    repeat with groupItem in groups
        --display alert " " & name of groupItem
        remove groupItem from groups

    end repeat
end tell
```

but it tells me that remove is not supported by that container. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. To remove all groups in a group I can just do

delete groups of currentGroup

I'm not sure how I would remove just a single group though.

Answer (score 2):

Such can be accomplished by for example the following:

```
tell application "Xcode"
tell front project
set parent_group to first group
delete first group of parent_group
end tell
end tell
```